# Exporting and importing Sharepoint Online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, continuous-integration

I'm working on a Sharepoint Online site, and I'd like to have three different site: a production one for the users, a staging one to demonstrate features, and a development one for myself.

I'd like to know if there's a solution for Sharepoint Online to do something like that: basically, importing and exporting the structure - Lists, Apps, as well as my own CSS/JS/HTML assets, while retaining the data specific to the site (the content of a list for instance).

Is there any way to do such a thing with Sharepoint Online ?

Comment: Look into the product called ShareGate.

Comment: Looks like it might do just what we want. However that solution is *way* out of our budget.